# Box like container FixedSizeBox<128, dyn SomeTrait> which can be constructed from type implementing SomeTrait

Tags: rust, containers, traits

I would like to implement a `FixedSizeBox` which behaves like the `Box` but owns the memory in which the object is stored. I introduced an additional parameter `CAPACITY` which defines the size of the memory which the `FixedSizeBox` will own.

The problem I encounter is that I am unable to use `dyn SomeTrait` as `FixedSizeBox` type and call `new` with a specific type.

Let's assume I have a trait `SomeTrait` and a struct `A` which implements that trait.

```rust
trait SomeTrait {}
struct A(u8);
impl SomeTrait for A {}
```

When I would like to store any object which implements `SomeTrait` in a `Box` I can write

```rust
let mut a: Box<dyn SomeTrait>;
a = Box::new(A { 0: 0 });
```

For the `FixedSizeBox` I would like to have the same functionality and implemented it like:

```rust
pub struct FixedSizeBox<const CAPACITY: usize, T: ?Sized> {
    _marker: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<const CAPACITY: usize, T> FixedSizeBox<CAPACITY, T> {
    pub fn new(_: T) -> FixedSizeBox<CAPACITY, T> {
        FixedSizeBox::<CAPACITY, T> {
            _marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}
```

When I use it in the same fashion as the `Box` the compiler fails:

```rust
let mut b: StackBox<128, dyn SomeTrait>;
// assigning a specific type leads to
// mismatched types
// expected struct `StackBox<dyn SomeTrait, 128_usize>`
//    found struct `StackBox<A, {_: usize}>` (rustc E0308)
b = StackBox::new(A { 0: 0 });
```

I looked into the `Box` and `Rc` implementations but was unable to figure out how rust actually realized this. Is there some trait missing?

As a side constraint, I would like to use stable rust. I could figure out that the nightly feature `CoerceUnsized`

```rust
impl<T, U> std::ops::CoerceUnsized<StackBox<U>> for FixedSizeBox<T>
where
    T: std::marker::Unsize<U> + ?Sized,
    U: ?Sized,
{
}
```

solves the issue but I would like to understand how this is realized in stable rust for `Box` so that I can apply it to the `FixedSizeBox`.

Comment: If the box has a fixed size how are you going to store unsized items? They may be larger than the size of the box.

Comment: For this case I intend to return a `Result` in `FixedSizeBox::new` which informs the user that the object does not fit in.
For simplicity I removed this part from the code snippets.

Comment: `Box` being part of the std lib, it is allowed to use unstable features even in stable Rust, and indeed [it uses `CoerceUnsized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/src/alloc/boxed.rs.html#1593-1594)

Answer (score 1):

`Box` is in the standard library, and as such it is allowed to use nightly features even on stable versions. You cannot do that without nightly.